# Stop printing receipt on last line drew

Tags: printing, receipt

I have a bixolon printer to print sales receipts. The printer is installed as a generic printer. 
The problem is that the printer keeps feeding empty paper after last line drew. Wasting paper in this way.
I want to find a way to stop the printer from doing this after the last line have been drew.
Things I already tried:
Changing papersize
Putting hasmorepages to false(This does not work because a printer prints the whole page size whether its full or has only one character in it)

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 10);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("Union Caribe N.V.".PadLeft(27));
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine("Date initialized: " + info.Initialized);
        sb.AppendLine("Date finalized: " + info.Finalized);
        sb.AppendLine("Office: " + info.Office);
        sb.AppendLine();

        Transaction transClient = new Transaction();
        foreach (var trans in info.Transactions)
        {
            foreach (Articulo item in trans.Items)
            {
                transClient.AddItem(item);
            }
        }

        foreach (SaleArticulo item in transClient.GetListOfItemsToShow())
        {
            sb.Append(item.Name.PadRight(17));
            sb.Append((item.Amount + "x" + item.Price).PadRight(8));
            sb.AppendLine((String.Format("{0:F0.00}", item.Total)).PadLeft(15));
        }
        sb.AppendLine("----------------------------------------");
        sb.AppendLine(("Total:").PadRight(32) + (String.Format("{0:F0.00}", info.Total)).PadLeft(8));
        sb.AppendLine("----------------------------------------");
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine("---------------------------".PadLeft(34));
        sb.AppendLine(("Signature.").PadLeft(25));
        sb.AppendLine((info.FirstName + " " + info.LastName).PadLeft(24));

        PrintText printText = new PrintText(sb.ToString(), font);
        SizeF layoutArea = new SizeF(e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height);
        SizeF stringSize = g.MeasureString(printText.Text, printText.Font, layoutArea, printText.StringFormat);
        RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(new PointF(), new SizeF(e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, stringSize.Height));
        g.DrawString(printText.Text, printText.Font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, rectf, printText.StringFormat);
```

I want the printing(printer) to stop after

```
sb.AppendLine((info.FirstName + " " + info.LastName).PadLeft(24)); line of code.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have code? If not this is not the correct place to be asking this. Stackoverflow is for specific coding problems not tech support.

Comment: I put the code i use for printing

Comment: This is more likely a printer question than a programming question.  The printer should have a command language, and you should be able to send a command in that language to set the receipt size.  What model printer are you using exactly?

Comment: Printer model is Samsung / Bixolon SRP-275. And its related to all printers of how to programmatically stop the printer at a certain time. In my case when the last line is drawn, but the question is not about the printer its about how to stop the printer programmatically. And I already tried setting the page (receipt) size as mentioned above to the desired size (string height size) and it still prints the whole page. Thanks for your help!